# How to print matrix values in OpenCvSharp library

Tags: c#, opencv, matrix, iterator

I'm trying to find homography matrix of two sources using `Cv2.FindHomography` method. Everything works fine up to here. The problem is that I cannot get/print matrix values. I'm really beginner-level for C#. I've found a sort of [documentation](http://paperplanetools.com/cvwd_doc/html/class_open_cv_sharp_1_1_mat_1_1_col_expr_indexer.html#details) belonging to it. However, I don't understand how to iterate over the values.

```
this[int startCol, int endCol]
override MatExpr OpenCvSharp.Mat.ColExprIndexer.this[int startCol, int endCol]
getset
Creates a matrix header for the specified column span.

Parameters
startCol    An inclusive 0-based start index of the column span.
endCol  An exclusive 0-based ending index of the column span.
Returns
```

My code,

```
Point2d[] points1 = new Point2d[]
{
  new Point2d(141, 131), new Point2d(480, 159)
};
Point2d[] points2 = new Point2d[]
{
  new Point2d(318, 256),
  new Point2d(5, 1)
};

Mat hCv = Cv2.FindHomography(points1, points2);
// I want to print the the resultant matrix
```

Answer (score 4):

First method is using `Data` method.

```
byte[] data = new byte[hCv.Width * hCv.Height];
Marshal.Copy(hCv.DataPointer, data, 0, hCv.Width * hCv.Height);

for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    // Print data[i]
}
```

Type depends on type of matrix, if its `CV_8`, then use `byte`, in case of `CV_32`, use `float` etc.

---

According to [this](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images) - another method is to create image or matrix (additional copy) and then access each elements

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> img = hCv.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
```

The pixel data can then be accessed using the `Image<,>.Data` property.

You can also convert the Mat to an Matrix<> object. Assuming the Mat contains 8-bit data

```
Matrix<Byte> matrix = new Matrix<Byte>(hCv.Rows, hCv.Cols, mat.NumberOfChannels);
hCv.CopyTo(matrix);
```

The pixel data can then be accessed using the `Matrix<>.Data` property.

Comment: It shows error up saying that `cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression type IntPtr`

Comment: @snr - I've edited the answer. Copy the data using `Marshal.Copy()` as shown above to byte array, then it should work. Also I've provided another methods I found.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that doesn't involve making a copy of the `Mat`:

```
for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < hCv.Rows; rowIndex++)
{
    for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < hCv.Cols; colIndex++)
    {
        Debug.Write($"{hCv.At<double>(rowIndex, colIndex)} ");
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
```

Just make sure the type inside the angle brackets (`double` in this case) is correct. Otherwise you'll get nonsense values.